# How to verify dataprovider is null or not?

Tags: java, excel, oracle, testng, testng-dataprovider

How we can verify whether the dataprovider (dataProvider="DataSet_Sheet1") we've got is null or not. Accordingly we'll skip that row and continue to next one.

Because if we've written any program to fetch data from an excel sheet and it doesn't have any record then there is no point in running the complete function?

Comment: if (dataProvider != null) {...

Comment: or `if (null != dataProvider)`, I would prefer this style.

Comment: Its a testNG dataprovider : @Test(dataProvider="DataSet_Sheet1")

Comment: Use `AssertNotNull`: http://tinyurl.com/n3q52js

Comment: This is how we create dataprovider:

**@DataProvider(name = "DataSet_Sheet1")
public Object[][] createArrayObject1() throws Exception 

{  
 
      Object[][] retObjArr = DataEngine.getTableArray(sFileName, sSheet1_sSheetName,"TestData");
      return (retObjArr);
}**

This is how we use it:

**@Test(dataProvider="DataSet_Sheet1")
public void test(String ID, String NAMESPACE) throws SQLException**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to verify that the 
dataGrid provider is null or not

you can do so by,

```
 myDataGrid.dataProvider==null OR 
    myDataGrid.dataProvider.source ==null
```

or cant you use an if statement?

```
if(example != null) 
{ 
   mydatagrid.dataprovider = {DataSet_Sheet1}; 
}
```

Comment: This is how we create dataprovider:

** @DataProvider(name = "DataSet_Sheet1")
public Object[][] createArrayObject1() throws Exception 

{  
 
      Object[][] retObjArr = DataEngine.getTableArray(sFileName, sSheet1_sSheetName,"TestData");
      return (retObjArr);
}**

This is how we use it:

**@Test(dataProvider="DataSet_Sheet1")
public void test(String ID, String NAMESPACE) throws SQLException**